# Zend Framework 2 Double Quotes in Queries

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-db, informix

I'm using the Zend Framework 2 for application developement. The whole application is based on a IBM Informix database.

The database configuration looks something like this:

```
return array(
'db' => array(
    'driver'         => 'Pdo',
    'dsn'            => 'dsn:connection:string',
    'driver_options' => array(
    ),
),
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
    ),
),
);
```

When querying the database by instantiating an Zend\Db\Sql\Select object, the queries are always getting quoted, which should not happen because Informix can't handle the query anymore.

**Expected Querystring:**

```
SELECT column1, column2 FROM table
```

**Zend-generated Querystring:**

```
SELECT "column1", "column2" from "table"
```

After some research I found similar cases, but neither solution was acceptable. The problem here is, that I have to pass an Zend\Db\Sql\Select object, so querying the database with raw sql via $dbAdapter->query($sql) is not possible.

Is there maybe a way to disable quotation(in the database configuration, e.g.)?

Some tipps would be very appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: why would you want to generate the SQL using Select, but then run a raw query? Either run the raw query OR use the Select builder to execute it for you...

Comment: You missunderstood - I wrote that I have to pass an Zend\Db\Sql\Select object, so querying the database via raw query is no alternative.

Comment: The answer might be here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813544/zf2-zend-db-adapter-platformgetquoteidentifiersymbol

Comment: Thanks sroes - this directed my in the right way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39593975/zf2-remove-column-quotes-in-query/39594164#39594164 on the query level it's self..

Answer (score 2):

you can disable quoting identifiers. like this

```
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter as DbAdapter;

// DB2 Connection
$adapter = new DbAdapter(array(
    'driver' => 'IbmDb2',
    'database' => '*LOCAL',
    'username' => '',
    'password' => '',
    'driver_options' => array(
        'i5_naming' => DB2_I5_NAMING_ON,
        'i5_libl' => 'LIB1 LIB2 LIB3'
    ),
    'platform_options' => array('quote_identifiers' => false)
);
```

taken from Zend Framework documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want Informix to recognize that notation, you need to set the environment variable DELIMIDENT so that the server knows to treat such double-quoted strings a identifiers instead of as strings.

There are a variety of ways to do it; which is best depends on your system.  It looks like you're using Windows rather than Unix.  There's a SETNET32 utility which could set the environment variable.  On Unix (not sure about Windows), you could add `DELIMIDENT 1` to `$HOME/.informix` or to `$INFORMIXDIR/etc/informixrc` (aconventional, but should work). You can set an env var by shell; you may be able to specify it as a connection-attribute.

Windows is not my area of expertise.