# ZF2 Remove column quotes in query

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, quotes

Since a while I am trying to remove the quotes of my mysql query in a ZF2 application. I need to remove the quotes to make this query works, testing the query over command line succeeded by removing the quotes around GEODIST().

```
$adapter = $serviceLocator->get('SphinxSearch\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
$sql     = new Sql($adapter);
$select  = new Select;
$select  ->columns(array('*', 'distance' => 'GEODIST(23.3556740442177, 2.9525189115381, latitude, longitude)'))
         ->from('table_name')
         ->where(array('distance > ?' => 250000))
         ->order('distance ASC')
         ->limit(25);

        echo $select->getSqlString(new SphinxQL());
```

**Outputs**

```
SELECT *, `GEODIST(23.3556740442177, 2.9525189115381, latitude, longitude)` AS `distance` FROM `table_name` ORDER BY `distance` ASC LIMIT 0,25
```

Comment: Do you really have a single-quote before `23.3556740442177`? Because that definitely shouldn't be there.

Comment: Excuse me! There isn't.. I needed to edit the code a bit, I am sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the follow solution to make this work by resetting the query with a simple replacer.

```
$statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
$statement ->setSql(str_replace('`', '', $statement->getSql()));
```

This did the job for me.